# Programmatically update database after successfull checkout

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal-express

I am creating a custom payment module using paypal api(Dont want to use any Magento Paypal Module). I am able to make the module work till the payment made. But I cant able to do the database update ,with the cart item, while coming back from paypal after successful checkout,with response.
Please help me how can I update the database while the checkout process is completed and return from Paypal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a controller that will accept the data returned from Paypal and direct it to Model that will do the database update.
In the Magento Paypal the controller is:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowController.php - returnUrlAction
```